# Mounting a directory to docker container

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to mount a host directory to my nginx docker container. However, it's not mounting what I would expect.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./app:/root/testfolder
```

Here's the contents of the directory in the container:

```
root@846e68e6e8b5:/# ls root/testfolder/
50x.html  index.html
```

And the directories on my host:

```
bash-3.2$ ls
app         bower.json      docker-compose.yml  gulpfile.js     node_modules        package.json
bash-3.2$ ls app/
app.js          assets      bower_components        common      index.html      modules
bash-3.2$
```

This is the current versions I am running:

```
OSX 10.10.5
Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

I'd expect the host directory `./app` to be mounted in `root/testfolder`. Why is this not the case?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your configuration. could you please give us more info. What OS are you using in your host? are you using docker-machine? What version of docker and compose are you using?

Comment: I've updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, docker has limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. By default Docker Machine tries to auto-share your `/Users` (OS X) or `C:\Users` (Windows) directory.

So the folder `/app` must be located somewhere under `/Users` directory in the host.

All other paths come from your virtual machine’s filesystem, so if you want to make some other host folder available for sharing, you need to do additional work. In the case of VirtualBox you need to make the host folder available as a shared folder in VirtualBox.