# Docker mount volumes is not working properly

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have spring application image which requires properties file to run successfully

I have started a jdk container and copied properties file to it. Now i am trying to run my spring imag(from jdk container) with properties file mounted as volume bind to the new container.

But, the volumes are not binded and the spring image is not running.

Docker command i am using is as below :

`docker run -d -v /workspace/e2e-tests/resources/log4j2.xml:/opt/frauscher/message-filter/etc/log4j2.xml -v /workspace/e2e-tests/resources/message-filter-application.properties:/opt/frauscher/message-filter/etc/application.properties --name message docker-fts.rep01.frauscher.intern/message-filter:latest`

I am getting below message from spring container :

`log4j2.xml must be available under /opt/frauscher/message-filter/etc/log4j2.xml
application.properties must be available under /opt/frauscher/message-filter/etc/application.properties`

Kindly help

Comment: Maybe permissions issue? Check files permissions.

Comment: usually the workspace folder doesn't reside in root e.g `/` are you sure this is the complete path? I suggest using Dockerfile instead of cmd line

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661720/mounting-a-directory-to-docker-container/35662285#35662285

Comment: @FranCruz files permissions are "rwxr--r--". its writable only by the created user. Do you think this could be the reason??

Comment: @shahaf workspace path is correct. I have created this workspace folder inside jdk container.

Comment: @HemersonVarela I am using Linux VM. I assume this answer is more specific to windows and mac. Kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I think on linux you don't have restrictions to access folders, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answers. Finally, i figured it out. docker is unable to mount volumes as we are running container inside another container with any volumes mounted on first container. I tried copying files to new container. It worked as expected.

Comment: So to add a property folder external from the container, you didn't use a volume? You created another container? Can you show how you bridged the two.

Answer (score 0):

here is a Dockerfile I'm using for my spring app, hopefully using this method you could run your app in docker or maybe pin point the problem
if this is not the solution you want to peruse, let me know and I will modify or delete this answer

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR opt

ADD app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ADD application.properties application.properties
ADD log4j2.xml log4j2.xml
EXPOSE 8080 

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

all files `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, `application.properties`, `og4j2.xml` should reside in the same folder as the `Dockerfile`

you can run `docker build .` and `docker run <image>` to start the container

Note: I'm using docker-compose to orchestrate multiple services like web, database and etc... this docker file is a draft taken out of my docker-compose configuration and modify to your needs (hopefully)

Comment: Itseems that you have added properties file to image. I do not want to add properties file into image. I want properties file to be mounted into spring boot container which runs the image.